# Navigation Drawer same as Foursquare

Tags: android, facebook, navigation

I want to make a navigation bar same the foursquare' navigation bar.

Below has the link of the example:
http://www.patterns.nikosaurier.me/image/75794965381

The user needs to login on Facebook before enter in my app. When he clicks on navigation bar, open the bar with the list of options and his photo.

Can anyone help me pls?

Ths.

Answer (score 0):

You seem like a beginner, `ListView`'s support multiple layouts, so you can create a `ListView` that does just that. Seeing the image, the `ListView` must have two views, one with the user's image and the other to be your application's menus (you can `setVisibility` on menu notifications as per need).

When creating `ListView`'s with different layouts you'll have to override the

1. `getViewTypeCount()` -> which returns the number of types of `View` in your `AdapterView`
2. `getItemViewType(int)` -> which returns the type of `View` you're trying to reference.

Code snippet:

Create an interface, so that we know what view we are working with, for example:

```
public interface ViewInterface {
    public int getType();
}
```

Extend all your classes with this interface, so that you can tell what type of view it is:
For this example we have the `HeaderView` and the `ContentView`:

```
public class HeaderView implements ViewInterface{

    public static final int HEADER_VIEW = 0;
    String title;

    public StayHeader create(String title){
        HeaderView header = new HeaderView();
        header.setTitle(title);
        return header;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return HEADER_VIEW;
    }
}


public class ContentView implements ViewInterface{

    public static final int CONTENT_VIEW = 1;

    String content;

    public ContentView create(String highlight){
        ContentView contents = new ContentView();
        contents.setHighlight(highlight);
        return highlights;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return CONTENT_VIEW;
    }
}
```

The `create()` method here is used to instantiate data for these views.

Your `Adapter` should now look like this:

```
public class DrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ViewInterface>{

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ViewInterface[] views;

    final int VIEW_TYPE_COUNT = 2;

    public StayEatDetailsAdapter(Context context, ViewInterface[] views, int layout) {
        super(context, layout, views);
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.views = views;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewInterface getItem(int position) {
        return views[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return views.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return VIEW_TYPE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return getItem(position).getType();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        ViewInterface typeView = getItem(position);
        // Initialize view according to interface's view type
        if(typeView.getType() == HeaderView.HEADER_VIEW){
            view = getHeaderView(convertView, parent, typeView);
        }
        else if(typeView.getType() == ContentView.CONTENT_VIEW) {
            view = getContentView(convertView, parent, typeView);
        }
        return view;
    }

    public View getHeaderView (View convertView, ViewGroup parent, ViewInterface typeView) {
        HeaderView headers = (HeaderView) typeView;
        HeaderItems headerItems = null;

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_stay_eat_header, parent, false);
            headerItems = new HeaderItems();
            headerItems.header = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header);
            convertView.setTag(headerItems);
        }
        if(headerItems == null) {
            headerItems = (HeaderItems) convertView.getTag();
        }

        headerItems.header.setText(headers.getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }

    public View getContentView (View convertView, ViewGroup parent, ViewInterface typeView) {
        ContentView contentItems = (ContentView) typeView;
        ContentItems contents = null;

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_stay_eat_highlights, parent, false);
            contents = new ContentItems();
            contents.content = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.highlights);
            convertView.setTag(highlight);
        }

        if(contentItems == null) {
            contentItems = (ContentView) convertView.getTag();
        }

        contents.content.setText(highlights.getHighlight());

        return convertView;
    }

    //View holder pattern for our view contents in the listview
    private class HeaderItems {
        TextView header;
    }

    private class ContentItems {
        TextView content;
    }

}
```

Finally initialize the `Adapter` and set it to the `ListView`:

```
ViewInterface views = new ViewInterface[2];
    views[1] = new HeaderView().create("Header");
    views[2] = new ContentView().create("Content");
    DrawerAdapter adapter = new StayEatDetailsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), views, layout);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is one way to do it, the other way would be to make an `xml` layout directly rather than using a `ListView`, which would look like this:

```
<DrawerLayout
    ...>
    <LinearLayout
        ...
        gravity="start">
        <!-- your views here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</DrawerLayout>
```

Hope this helps :)

For reference : [See this cool article : ListView](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/07/05/listview-tips-tricks-2-section-your-listview/) :), [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) and also [this](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).